# JQuery $.getJSON asynchronous workaround - caching ajax results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, asynchronous

I am caching the JSON returned from ajax calls and then displaying the results from the cache.  My issue is if there is no cache for that Ajax call already, the results only display on refresh.  This is down to the fact that ajax is asynchronous but how do I get around that?  Ajax async:false has been deprecated so that's not an option.  Would the  **$.getJSON .done()** function suffice or is there a better way?

Here is my code so far:

```
if ((online === true)) {
    //get JSON
    $.getJSON(baseurl + '/wp-json/app/v2/files?filter[category]' + cat + '&per_page=100', function(jd) {
        //cache JSON
        var cache = {
            date: new Date(),
            data: JSON.stringify(jd)
        };
        localStorage.setItem('cat-' + cat, JSON.stringify(cache));
    });
    //if not online and no cached file
} else if ((online === false) && (!cache['cat-' + cat])) {
    alert('There are no cached files.  You need to be online.');
}

//get cached JSON
cache['cat-' + cat] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cat-' + cat));
var objCache = cache['cat-' + cat].data;
objCache = JSON.parse(objCache); //Parse string to json
//display JSON results from cache
$.each(objCache, function(i, jd) {
    var thumb = jd.file_thumbnail.sizes.medium;
    //.....etc...
    )
}}
```

Comment: `ajax is asynchronous but how do I get around that` - don't go around it, embrace it, and learn to use it

Comment: Alternatively, provide the initial data via server-side code when the page is initially generated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple rewrite of your code yields the following:

```
function cacheAsCacheCan(cat, callback) {
    if (online === true) {
        //get JSON
        $.getJSON(baseurl + '/wp-json/app/v2/files?filter[category]' + cat + '&per_page=100', function(jd) {
            //cache JSON
            var cache = {
                date: new Date(),
                data: JSON.stringify(jd)
            };
            localStorage.setItem('cat--' + cat, JSON.stringify(cache));
        });
        //if not online and no cached file
    } else if ((online === false) && (!cache['cat-' + cat])) {
        callback('There are no cached files.  You need to be online.');
        return;
    }
    //get cached JSON
    callback(null, cache['cat-' + cat] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cat-' + cat)));
}

cacheAsCacheCan('someCat', function(error, cachedata) {
    if(error) {
        alert(error);
    } else {
        var objCache = cachedata.data;
        objCache = JSON.parse(objCache); //Parse string to json
        //display JSON results from cache
        $.each(objCache, function(i, jd) {
                var thumb = jd.file_thumbnail.sizes.medium;
                //.....etc...
            )
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks for your respnse, I have tried you code but keep getting, "index.html:387 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null"  which is the following line:  //get cached JSON
    callback(null, cache['cat-' + cat] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(cache['cat-' + cat]))  );

Comment: that's because I copied your code verbatim ... `cat--`  in the `localStorage.setItem` is wrong ... should be `cat-`

Comment: sorry I dont understand

Comment: look at the line `localStorage.setItem('cat--' + cat, JSON.stringify(cache));` ... it says cat-- ... 2x - ... instead of cat- ... as I said, copied directly from YOUR QUESTION

Comment: Yes, sorry, my fault.  However that was a mistake when copying the code over, its not in my actual code that Im running.  The JSON is caching fine, but isn't displaying.  Looks like var objCache = cachedata.data; is empty?

Comment: Aahhh just realised if I refresh the page it works, therefore this change of code hasn't made a difference :(